# The Simulator select button can't find

Tags: xcode

My Mac system is El Capitan 10.11.2，in Xcode 7.2，I can look the simulator； but when I install Xcode 6.4，open project (every project like it)，I can't find Simulator button.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to  `Window` and then `Devices`, check if it appear there and if not - click the `+` icon in the lower left

Comment: This method is not used,they are on the left,